# Certbot Redirection of HTTP to HTTPS from Nginx not working

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, certbot

[Certbot command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgke6.png)

[SSL Connection Error returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBNYh.png)

I am trying to issue an SSL certificate for my website, although the message was successful (as attached image) but when accessing that domain, it is not working

Comment: It is not enough to issue cert. You need to properly configure nginx to provide that cert for https connections, configure firewall or iptables to enable/forward 443 port, etc.

Comment: @AlexeyR.: `certbox --nginx` makes the nginx changes automatically, but system-level and network-level are your responsibility (and are likely to manifest as connection timeout)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Cloudflare, go to SSS/TLS tab, then go to Overview, then on the right side of the page, select Full(strict)

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure to configure it in Nginx also:

```
ssl_certificate /path/to/certificate.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /path/to/certificate_key.key;
```

And make sure the server is listening on port 443.

If you want to force `https://` then add a new nginx server declaration listening only on port 80 with the following:

```
location / {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

There may be better ways to do that also, but I have little information to go on from this question, with no further information provided, I don't even know if you already did this or not, but it wouldn't work to just generate a cert, you also have to use it.

Comment: `certbot --nginx` makes the required config changes (in nginx) automatically.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 oh, and I now see that they used --nginx. Then you are correct. I apologize.